# get the height of activity ( that is usable and visible )

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, height

I want to insert a GraphView into a LinearLayout to show it ( graph ) on the screen and because of GraphView limitations I can't use android:layout_height="wrap_content" for my LinearLayout so I'm going to use LinearLayout.setScaleY code to make GraphView fill the screen.
now, I want to ask :

--- Is there any better way to make LinearLayout fill the screen without android:layout_height="wrap_content" code ?

If not, how can I get the activity's real usable height to use it in my code instead of metrics.heightPixels ?
+ that I've set the height of LinearLayout 500dp, so I used 500 in my code...

my code is here :

```
LinearLayout mLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLL);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    mLL.setScaleY(metrics.heightPixels/(float)500);

    mLL.addView(mGraphView);
```

THANK YOU :)

---

SOLVED ! ( I can't answer my question until next few hours because of low reputation, so I've edited my post... :) )

I had to define LinearLayout in XML file like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mlinearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

as you can see, I have used android:layout_height="100dp" and android:layout_above="@+id/mlinearLayout2" ( I have used another linear layout under mLinearLayout ) codes together and then Graph was viewable without any ForceClose in a FullScreen LinearLayout :)
I hope this post help others to solve their similar problems easily with some changes in codes !:)

I've found out this, too : If you want to get LinearLayout height anyway, you can use this code :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (hasFocus == true) {
    LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
    int layoutWidth = myLinearLayout.getWidth();
    int layoutHeight = myLinearLayout.getHeight();
}
}
```

Comment: wrap_content will never fill the screen. Use fill_parent instead.

Comment: thank you but you didn't understand my problem correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

I dont know if gives the same output as yours but worth a try.
Based on metrics.heightPixels i think you can adjust your view's dimensoins

Comment: Thank you, but the same result... :( You mean I shout change the code like this for example? : mLL.setScaleY((metrics.heightPixels-50)/(float)500);   but is the value I should use instead of 50 the same for all devices and android versions ?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the internet for an easy way, but could not find one after hours of searching.

This is what I used, because there is no way (it seems) to get this value directly. I first get the dimensions of the Display. I obtain the height of the action and notifiaction bar and substract them:

```
int height = 0;

private void obtainHeight() {
    int actionBarHeight = 0;
    int notificationBarHeight = 0;

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    height = size.y;

    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    int resourceIdStatusBar = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceIdStatusBar > 0) {
        notificationBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceIdStatusBar);
    }

    height = height - actionBarHeight - notificationBarHeight;
}
```

Navigation bar you can get with (not needed to be substracted, because its usually not part of the display):

```
 Resources resources = this.getResources();
 int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
 if (resourceId > 0) {
       naviigationBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
 }
```